# handle repetitive model creates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am using Rspec in Rails. I am currently testing one of my models. This specific model is seeded into the database with 5 records. Each record has a name attribute with a seeded value. For example:

```
  def self.seed
    find_or_create_by(name: 'Text')
    find_or_create_by(name: 'Number')
    find_or_create_by(name: 'Date')
    find_or_create_by(name: 'Time')
    find_or_create_by(name: 'Boolean')
  end
```

I want to test the creation of each one in Rspec. And currently I am doing this:

```
describe FieldType, type: :model do
  context "when :name is text"  do
    let(:field_type) { FieldType.create(name: "Text") }

    it { expect(field_type).to be_persisted }
    it { expect(field_type.name).to eq("Text")}
    it { expect(field_type.type_from_field).to be(String) }
  end

  context "when :name is number"  do
    let(:field_type) { FieldType.create(name: "Number") }

    it { expect(field_type).to be_persisted }
    it { expect(field_type.name).to eq("Number")}
    it { expect(field_type.type_from_field).to be(Integer) }
  end

  ...
```

Is this the right way to test this behavior? Or is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: I'd just have a list of tuples, string type and expected class, iterate, and have a single chunk of expectations. But what specifically are you testing here? `find_or_create_by` is Rails itself, and the persisted and field name are duplicating Rails' own tests. If you have custom mapping for name-to-type then just test that function. If you want to test the seeding then just check for the entries--although there are seed mechanisms already built in to Rails.

Comment: @DaveNewton You would put the list of tuples in a before block and then iterate through them in a single example?

Comment: @Donato: no, he likely meant something like this: https://pastebin.com/xSDQ35Yi (that is, generate the tests/assertions dynamically, based on what you have in that list of tuples)

Comment: What Sergio said. RSpecs are just code, and can be written as such :)

Comment: Don't test Rails, or library functionality. Only test your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the System Under Test here is the method `.seed`; so, maybe something like this:

```rb
describe FieldType do
  describe '.seed' do
    before do
      described_class.seed
    end

    it 'creates the expected records' do
      expect(described_class.pluck(:name)).to match_array(['Text', 'Number', 'Date', 'Time', 'Boolean'])
    end
  end
end
```

Also please check [Better Specs](http://www.betterspecs.org/) for some recommendations and [rubocop-rspec](https://github.com/rubocop-rspec/rubocop-rspec) for automatically checking your code against some RSpec best practices.